# Providing custom filename is not working in table2excel jquery?

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel

i have used jquery code to export table data into excel file, got code from [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html)

but providing custome file name is not working it is taking random filename. 
how to provide custom file name from code.

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){
        $("#example").table2excel({
                exclude: ".noExl",
        name: "Employee"
        }); 
         });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` variable in this plugin refers to the name of the worksheet, not the name of the Excel file.

If you want to be able to change the filename, you'll have to hack the plugin code a bit, or just use another plugin or piece of code that suits your needs, like [this one](http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/javascript-export-html-table-to-excel-with-custom-file-name/) (where you can put the filename in the `postfix` variable).

Comment: You'll have to add a few html lines at the beginning of the div that contains your table. See [this](http://forums.codecharge.com/posts.php?post_id=107155) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

1.Open jquery.table2excel.js

2.Find `function getFileName(settings)`

3.Change it to

```
function getFileName(settings) {
        return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : settings.name ) +
               ( settings.fileext ? settings.fileext : ".xls" );
}
```

settings.name is variable from your custom js scripts when u call jquery2excel
In my example it looks like

```
$(".generateXLS").click(function(){
    var idOfTable = $(this).attr("data-rel");
    var tableName = $(this).attr("data-table-name");
    $("#tableN"+idOfTable).table2excel({
        name: tableName
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hack table2excel jquery to give customized name for download as follow:

From your js:

```html
<script>
$(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){
        $("#example").table2excel({
                exclude: ".noExl",
        name: "Employee.txt" //This name will be passed for download
        }); 
         });
});
</script>
```

Then change getFileName(e.settings) call in table2excel.js to name as follow:

```html
if (typeof msie !== "undefined" && msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
            {
                if (typeof Blob !== "undefined") {
                    //use blobs if we can
                    fullTemplate = [fullTemplate];
                    //convert to array
                    var blob1 = new Blob(fullTemplate, { type: "text/html" });
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob1, name ); // Changed Here
                } else {
                    //otherwise use the iframe and save
                    //requires a blank iframe on page called txtArea1
                    txtArea1.document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    txtArea1.document.write(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
                    txtArea1.document.close();
                    txtArea1.focus();
                    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, name ); // Changed Here
                }

            } else {
                link = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
                a = document.createElement("a");
                a.download = name;  // Changed Here
                a.href = link;

                document.body.appendChild(a);

                a.click();

                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit or add anything table2excel plugin include parameter for file name.
So now you  have two parameters the first is **name** its for the worksheet name, and another parameter **filename** its dedicated for the excel file name you can check the code below .

```
$("#example").table2excel({
                exclude: ".noExl",
                name: "Employee",
                filename : "EmployeeFileName",
});
```

for further information's you can look into **jquery.table2excel.js**  file 
it has this code line which explain everything.

```
 function getFileName(settings) {
        return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") + ".xlsx";
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function ResultsToTable(){    
  $("#sales_dataTable").table2excel({
    exclude: ".noExl",
    // name: "Results"
    filename: 'Sales_Report',
  });
}
```

Comment: just add filename: testing_report you can change export file name thank you.